# When to use "the" and when to take it out

Tags: grammar, word-usage, rules

I've a question about the usage of "the". I had written the sentence with "the" and I've been told to take it out because they said it's redundant, however, I disagree. Thoughts, grammar rules...?

*Once we have completed your registration, you’ll receive a confirmation email which will include all **the** transfer details.*

Comment: Grammar / usage rules: either is acceptable; the variant without 'the' is terser, more modern- and perhaps more professional-sounding. More important rules: in grey areas, do what your boss / editor / professor recommends.

Comment: Five downvotes in just 31 page views for this innocent question from a site newcomer? That really says "Get off my lawn!" with a vengeance.

Answer (score 0):

I remember the "K.I.S.S" principle in my business exam. "Keep it short and simple" For example:

**you’ll receive a confirmation email**

..which includes the complete transfer details.

or shorter

..including all transfer details.